# file copying in while loop is executing for one time only

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, sh

I am checking the logs with conditional checks and copy to the other folder.The while loop is executing fine for first iteration. In the next iteration the file copy is not working. here is my code.

```
current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
tail -n 0 -F hive-server2.log | \
while read LINE
do
if [ `echo "$LINE" | grep -c "DROP" ` -gt 0 ]
then
  AuditTypeID=14
  QueryResult="$(grep -oEi 'DROP TABLE [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*' hive-server2.log | sed -n \$p)"
echo -e "$QueryResult" >/dev/null < op.txt
cp op.txt op/op.txt.$current_time
fi
done
```

In the first iteration, The output file is created and stored in the op directory. In the next iteration the file is not creating.

Expected output :
for every iteration new file should be created in the op directory.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How is the `$current_time` variable being populated?

Comment: Still how many times are you planning on to ask this question - https://stackoverflow.com/users/8235369/teju-priya?tab=questions

Comment: What do you think this line does - `echo -e "$QueryResult" >/dev/null < op.txt`. It is incorrect and does _not_ do what you expect to do

Comment: @Teju Priya, why don't you show us sample input and sample output in code tags so that we could help you on same in a code.

Comment: Why do you expect a new file to be created?  the output filename does not change within the loop.

Comment: No I am adding timestamp for that purpose. If new query is passed, It should create a another file with respective timestamp

Comment: @TejuPriya `echo -e "$QueryResult" >/dev/null < op.txt` what u trying to achieve here with the file `op.txt` ? it makes me no meaning.

Comment: @ThiruShetty I am trying the save the queries output to op.txt file.After that I will move the op.txt to new folder with timestamp.

Comment: @ThiruShetty in the next iteration the while loop does not copy the file to new folder.For 5-6 iterations it creates 1 file only. that is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

```
tail -n 0 -F hive-server2.log | \
while read LINE
do
if [ `echo "$LINE" | grep -c "DROP" ` -gt 0 ]
then
  current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
  AuditTypeID=14
  QueryResult="$(grep -oEi 'DROP TABLE [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*' hive-server2.log | sed -n \$p)"
  echo -e "$QueryResult" > op/op.txt.$current_time > /dev/null 2>&1
  #cp op.txt op/op.txt.$current_time
fi
done
```

Comment: @TejuPriya the answer works if it enters into `if condition` every time, if not you need to check the condition what you filtering is exist in every iteration

Comment: No again its creating one file only. I tried running 5-6 times. overall it created 1 file only.

Comment: I dont know what is the problem, I am struggling for last 2 days with this issue.

Comment: Add the following line inside `if` i mean after the line `AuditTypeID=14` as  `echo "entered inside if condition with time : $current_time"` and execute and see how many times it prints and as well time value. I suspect $current_time doesn't change, so it overwriting the file.

Comment: Good catch ! the timestamp is the issue. The current time is not changing

Comment: can you edit ur code with how you populating `current_time` ?

Comment: Sure I will add now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168027/discussion-between-thiru-shetty-and-teju-priya).